# Fullcalendar select: check if allDay

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I am using Fullcalendar to make a scheduler.

I am trying to pass information to a form which will add the event information.
I am now trying to figure out if an event is allDay or not.

What I am doing to test this out is to alert onscreen if the allDay box at the top of the calendar was selected.  If so, alert 'is all day'.  I have been reading about using .hasTime() but it won't work.

Really I want to populate a hidden input on createEventModal called allDay with a 0 for 'not full day' and a 1 for 'allDay' to save it in my mySQL db.

Here's the code I'm working on to see if the selected event is allDay. So far, it always alerts 'not full day', even if the allDay section is selected.

```
select: function(start, end, allDay) {
                var starttime = moment(start).format('MMMM Do YYYY h:mm a'); 
                var endtime = moment(end).format('h:mm a'); 


                var start = moment(start).format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ'); 
                var end = moment(end).format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ');

                var location_id =  "<?php echo $location->data()->id; ?>";
                var contact_id =  "<?php echo $contact->data()->id; ?>";
                var company_id =  "<?php echo $user->data()->company_id; ?>";


                var mywhen = starttime + ' - ' + endtime;
                var contactname = "<?php echo $contact->data()->first; ?>" + " " + "<?php echo $contact->data()->last; ?>";

                var m = $.fullCalendar.moment(starttime);
                if (m.hasTime()) { alert ('not full day'); } else { alert('full day'); };

                $('#createEventModal #start').val(start);
                $('#createEventModal #end').val(end);
                $('#createEventModal #allDay').val(allDay);
                $('#createEventModal #when').text(mywhen);
                $('#createEventModal #contact_name').text(contactname);
                $('#createEventModal #contact_id').val(contact_id);
                $('#createEventModal #location_id').val(location_id);
                $('#createEventModal #company_id').val(company_id);
                $('#createEventModal').modal();

       },
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured something out.  This will alert the proper true or false values for the selected time depending on if an allDay blocked is being added to my DB.

```
select: function(start, end, jsEvent, view) {
                var starttime = moment(start).format('MMMM Do YYYY h:mm a'); 
                var endtime = moment(end).format('h:mm a'); 
                var allDay = !start.hasTime() && !end.hasTime();
                alert(allDay);
```